# Programmatically adding, deleting and committing files into a subversion repository using Delphi

Tags: delphi, svn

I would like to programmatically check if a file is versioned, and add, delete and commit files into a subversion repository using Delphi.

Does anyone have sample code that might help me create the necessary functions and procedures?

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: Greg and I have assumed you want to include Subversion support in your own project. Marco, on the other hand, assumed you want to write a Delphi plug-in to manage your project's source files from within the Delphi IDE. Please clarify.

Comment: I want to add it to my own project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Delphi XE integration is open source (MPL based license). You can get the code at [radstudioverins](http://sourceforge.net/projects/radstudioverins/) on SourceForge.

take a look at trunk/svn/SvnClient.pas, and let me know if it's what you're looking for.  It is a nice looking wrapper around libsvn.

Comment: This looks like what I'm after. I'm not seeing any documentation though, so it's hard to know for sure. Have you used this?

Comment: This looks like what I'm after. Have you used this?

The terminology used below is based on my experience with TortoiseSVN: 

Users will request my application to add, edit and delete files in a folder under version control. 

If the file isn't yet versioned (I need a way to determine this from SVNClient.pas), I would like to add, then commit it (using SVNClient.pas). If a file being added is in version control, I'd like to commit it. If a file being deleted is in version control, I'd like to delete and commit it.

Do you have any examples that might get me started?

Comment: I have no examples at hand... you should take a look at the files in the svnui/svnide folder.  As you may know, delphiXE let's you do a complete series of svn operations from inside the IDE, and all the code for this is in this project.

In other words... anything you can do from Delphi XE IDE is here.  You can learn how to do things by yourself inspecting the code (as I usually do)

Comment: Just tried to include this into my project and it went well, until the point of loading the .dlls - my project is 64 bit and the subversion dlls provided with Delphi seem to be 32-bit only :( Ah well, back to cmdLine ..

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to call the `svn` command line program, passing it the relevant commands and arguments to do whatever it is you want to do. Although there are probably Delphi-compatible Subversion API bindings, calling `svn` is undoubtedly going to be more straightforward.

Most `svn` command line commands have an `--xml` switch that writes the output in program-friendly XML format, instead of making you rely on fragile text parsing.

Answer (score 1):

The most recent version, Delphi XE has Subversion integration by default.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Subversion library](http://svn.collab.net/svn-doxygen/group__clnt__wc.html). That's what TortoiseSVN does.