# How to create a TSvnItem for a specified URL

Tags: delphi, svn

## Short Version

How to perform `svn cat` in Delphi's subversion api wrapper?

## Long Version

I want to get the contents of a file in subversion.

Here's a random public repository that lets you [`cat`](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.cat.html) (i.e. display the contents of) a file:

```
>svn cat http://svn.code.sf.net/p/unicon/code/trunk/unicon/README
Unicon 13.x README


This is the Unicon distribution.  Please tell us
where it compiles, and when and how it doesn't.
...snip...
```

So that works.

### Now how to do it in Delphi?

How do i read the contents (i.e. `cat`) a file in Delphi's Subversion API wrapper?

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7981354/12597) Stackoverflow answer, i try:

```
SvnItem: TSvnItem;

SvnItem := TSvnItem.Create(SvnClient, nil, 'http://svn.code.sf.net/p/unicon/code/trunk/unicon/README');
```

Unfortunately the call to create a **TSvnItem** throws an exception:

> EAprError: The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters

So what am i doing wrong?

## For The Lazy

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
    SysUtils, SvnClient;

procedure Main;
var
    SvnClient: TSvnClient;
    SvnItem: TSvnItem;
    url: string;
begin
    // Set the global variable where the subversion DLLs can be found.
    BaseDllDir := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)); //Setting a global variable (yes, seriously)

    SvnClient := TSvnClient.Create;
    SvnClient.Initialize;

    url := 'http://svn.code.sf.net/p/unicon/code/trunk/unicon/README';
    SvnItem := TSvnItem.Create(SvnClient, nil, url);
end;

begin
    try
        Main;
    except
        on E: Exception do
            begin
                ExitCode := 1;
                Writeln(Format('[%s] %s', [E.ClassName, E.Message]));
            end;
    end;
end.
```

### See also

- https://sourceforge.net/projects/radstudioverins/
- [Programmatically adding, deleting and committing files into a subversion repository using Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4047177/12597)
- [reading SVN:externals from working copy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7980679/12597)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an answer; but it is a workaround for the next guy.

### Thing that should work (but doesn't)

```
function GetSubversionFileContents(Client: TSvnClient; Url: string): TStream;
var
    item: TSvnItem;
    buffer: TBytes;
    ms: TMemoryStream;
begin
    //WARNING: This code doesn't work.
    item := TSvnItem.Create(Client, nil, Url); //throws exception
    buffer := item.GetBaseFile;
    item.Free;

    ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
    ms.Size := Length(buffer);
    if Length(buffer) > 0 then
        ms.Write(buffer[0], Length(buffer));
    ms.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
end;
```

### Hack workaround

```
function GetSubversionFileContents(Client: TSvnClient; Url: string): TStream;
var
    http: IWinHttpRequest;
    stm: IStream;
begin
    // Issue the WebDAV HTTP GET ourselves.
    // (SVN is just a wrapper around WebDAV)

    http := CoWinHttpRequest.Create;
    http.Open('GET', url, False);
    if Client.UserName <> '' then
        http.SetCredentials(Client.UserName, Client.Password, HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER);
    http.Send(EmptyParam);

    stm := IUnknown(http.ResponseStream) as IStream;
    Result := TOleStream.Create(stm);

    //TODO: Re-write the rest of the Subversion API into something modern (i.e. post-1995).
end;
```

Subversion is just an implementation of **WebDAV** - which is just **REST** but without the cool name. Which means you can issue a `GET` to the url to get the contents yourself directly.